# youtube recommendation on tor browser

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

When I navigate to youtube.com after starting up Tor Browser, I often notice a video recommendation from my non-anonymous, chrome-based youtube viewing. It is almost inconceivable that this video is popular enough to land on the youtube homepage without some targeting. The topic is esoteric and the views are about 100k, a fraction of the videos that show up on the homepage. Is this expected behavior?

I am using the tor browser with the only modifications to the default install being 1) adblock and 2) I have on occasion allowed plugins while on youtube. I never visited a site using the tor browser other than youtube.com (and the default homepage). I use Tor Browser in parallel with chrome. I also have googledrivesync always running as a service.

Comment: It is not a good idea to view flash contents through standard tbb, it will very probably leak your IP and defeat the very purpose of you using tbb; being anonymous.

Answer (score 2):

Persistent cookies are cross-browser, actually. Check it [here](http://samy.pl/evercookie/) and you will see which components are elaborated - it shows you all the process step-by-step in **your very own case** Also [browserleaks](https://www.browserleaks.com/) can be of some more help